# installing app and get result

Tags: android

I installed an app to my device:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(apk_file, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

But how can I receive a result of installing (is app installing ok or user cancel installing)